# terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost: Permission denied'

Tags: ros, create-autonomy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While running roslaunch ca_driver create_2.launch I receive this error. I have used the command for $ sudo usermod -a -G dialout $administartor, logged out and logged in again but it still doesn't work.

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_implboost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::system::system_error >'
what():  open: Permission denied

[ca_driver-2] process has died [pid 7759, exit code -6, cmd /home/administrator/create_ws/devel/lib/ca_driver/ca_driver __name:=ca_driver __log:=/home/administrator/.ros/log/f3f9e360-23ee-11e7-a992-f46d04793b72/ca_driver-2.log].
log file: /home/administrator/.ros/log/f3f9e360-23ee-11e7-a992-f46d04793b72/ca_driver-2*.log

Please help. Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259468/terminate-called-after-throwing-an-instance-of-%27boost:-permission-denied%27/) by [Awais](https://answers.ros.org/users/30062/awais/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-04-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) on 2017-04-18**:
Can you post the output of `ls /dev/tty*`? Which robot base are you using? Create 2?

**Comment by [Awais](https://answers.ros.org/users/30062/awais/) on 2017-04-18**:
Thank you for your response. I am using Create 2 directly connected to computer via USB cable. Actually I am just beginning to work on ROS and Ubuntu and doesn't know how to check the output at "ls /dev/tty*". When I try with the code with USB cable removed it gives the same error: No such file or d

**Comment by [Awais](https://answers.ros.org/users/30062/awais/) on 2017-04-18**:
"No such file or directory". I have also tried launching Create 1 it also returns the same error with: Permission denied. The rostopics being published are :
/diagnostics
/joint_states
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/tf
/tf_static

**Comment by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) on 2017-04-18**:\

1. Connect the cable to your computer and robot
2. Make sure the robot is powered on (main LED should be green)
3. Open a terminal and run the command `ls /dev/tty*`. Copy and paste the output here.

Are you using a virtual machine by chance?

**Comment by [Awais](https://answers.ros.org/users/30062/awais/) on 2017-04-18**:
It gives the following list /dev/tty    /dev/tty23  /dev/tty39  /dev/tty54      /dev/ttyS10  /dev/ttyS26...
...../dev/ttyS9   /dev/tty2   /dev/tty35  /dev/tty50  /dev/tty9       /dev/ttyS22  /dev/ttyUSB0

This /dev/tty/USB0 goes off when I remove the cable and shows again when I plug in th cable ag

**Comment by [Awais](https://answers.ros.org/users/30062/awais/) on 2017-04-19**:
Thanks for your help. It is working for me now. I think there was authorization problem. I run the this command
$ sudo -s
and then this
$source ~/create_ws/devel/setup.bash
and launched create_2 which is now working. Thanks.

**Comment by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) on 2017-04-19**:
Glad you hear it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Every time I got this error, i will just to run

```
sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyUSB0
```

then create_autonomy will work.
But I makes me wonder how to permanently add this USB permission to Ubuntu?

---

Originally posted by [fj138696](https://answers.ros.org/users/30352/fj138696/) with karma: 30 on 2017-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) on 2017-05-31**:
Try `sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER` and then logout/login. ([reference](https://github.com/autonomylab/create_autonomy#usb-permissions))